# Get "is ready" signal after rendering of WPF toolkit chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I am using the charting stuff of the WPF toolkit.
After creating a chart I like to have a snaphshot of that chart, without visualizing that chart. My problem is that I don't know when the rendering process is done, so I can create a snapshot.
I tried listening to the "LayoutUpdated" event, but the chart is being updated very often.

Can anyone tell me how to find out if the chart is completely rendered?

Comment: Can you not inherit a chart, override the render and call a custom event after base.Render() or equivalent has completed?

Comment: There is only OnRender that could make sense to override. But the handler is invoked after the chart is initialized and not after the content has changed.

Comment: @flashflail, did you manage to solve that? I've got exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dispatcher in your code behind:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() =>
    {
        // code in here should be executed after chart has been rendered.
    }
));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The code inside the BeginInvoke is executed before the chart is rendered. I also tried it with DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, doesn't work either.

Comment: No, doesn't work for me either. I thought it would, but I downloaded the toolkit charts and tried it and lo and behold, the method executed before the chart was rendered. It does work for other controls though, I think the reason it doesn't work it because of the animations used by the chart. If there's any way of disabling these you might have more luck. [This post has some info that might help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/01/13/i-feel-the-need-the-need-for-speed-seven-simple-performance-boosting-tweaks-for-common-silverlight-wpf-charting-scenarios.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The Loaded event sounds like what you need.

```
MyChart.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
{
    // chart has been loaded but not yet rendered
}
```

where "MyChart" is a the name you've given the chart in your XAML.

I'm not sure how well this works with frequent updates, but this link seems to indicate http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx that this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I attached an event handler to the loaded event, but it is never fired. Could the reason be that the chart isn't visualized?